# POST method needed to send Params.bin to IP cam

Tags: vbscript, http-post

My IP cam sets itself back to default at times. I have a script that can run a VBS every two hours or so. I want the vbs to send the Params file to the cam even when I'm not there.

Here is what I've been working on all day. So far the best thing that happened was "Network Error"

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate("about:blank")
IE.AddressBar = False
IE.ToolBar = True
IE.StatusBar = True
IE.Resizable = False
IE.Visible = True
DataToPOST1 = "C:\Users\Garo\Desktop\params.bin"
Header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WScript.Sleep 5000
post = "/restore_params.cgi?"&"user=admin&pwd="""
IE.Navigate "192.168.1.17" & post, Nothing, Nothing, StringToBinary(DataToPOST1), Header

Function StringToBinary(str)
  Dim tmpArr()
  Dim i
  ReDim tmpArr(Len(str))
  For i = 1 Ro Len(str)
    tmpArr(i-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(str,i,1)))
  Next
  StringToBinary = tmpArr
End Function
```

Comment: if possible, please add error log for further understanding to users.

Comment: Try `ie.Navigate url, , , data, header` instead of `ie.Navigate url, Nothing, Nothing, data, header` and make sure the URL includes the protocol specifier (`http://` or `https://`). Did you check with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) that you got the request right? Also, please show the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: This works but I have to be there to select the file and press Upload.<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>upload params</title>
<base target="_top" href="http://192.168.1.17/">
</head>
<body>
<form action="restore_params.cgi?next_url=index.htm&user=admin&pwd="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="C:\Users\Garo\Desktop\params.bin" size="20">&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Upload to cam">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I tried                                                                                             IE.Navigate "192.168.1.17" & post, , , tringToBinary(DataToPOST1), Header.  Error is IE opens and says 'error: network error.'

Comment: restore_params.cgi
Description: The parameter is set to restore previous backup
Permissions: manager
Grammer: / restore_params.cgi [? User = & pwd = & next_url =]
Note: The cgi must use post method, the parameters of the previous backup set file
package sent to the ip camera

Comment: Please do not bury information in comments. If you need to provide additional information to your question: edit your question.